# Monitoring jboss using JMX remotely

Tags: jboss, jmx, remoting

We are trying to monitor jboss using jmx from a remote machine using jconsole:

`jboss Version: jboss-eap-6.4`
`jdk version: 1.7.079`

To achieve this, I have done below changes in jboss configuration:

Added below parameters in `Domain.sh` :

```
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -    Djavax.management.builder.initial=org.jboss.system.server.jmx.MBeanServerBuilderImpl"
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Djboss.platform.mbeanserver"
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=IP.of.machine"
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=4847"
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false"
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false"
```

Below is configured in `domain.xml`

```
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jmx:1.3">
            <expose-resolved-model/>
            <expose-expression-model/>
            <remoting-connector use-management-endpoint="false"/>
        </subsystem>
```

`Defined an ApplicationRealm user with the help of add-user.sh`

After doing this much, I am able to monitor the jboss via jmx through local server (on which jboss is running) using below url:

`service:jmx:remoting-jmx://ip.of.machine:4847`

However, when I am trying to provide the same url from the remote machine, I am getting below exception.

`The connection to xxxxx did not succeed'.

I need a help on this, to know if I am doing something incorrect. so that I can monitor jboss using JMX console remotely.

**update**
There is no firewall in between source and destination.

Comment: Have you already confirmed that there isn't a firewall that is blocking communication on the port from the remote machine to the host machine?

Comment: @M.Rizzo , yes this is already been conformed. I have updated my question with this.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have JBOSS installed on the remote machine?  JBOSS notes that "If you are running jconsole on a machine different than the server you need to have a local JBoss installation: the Java JRE's jconsole will not work out of the box (i.e., without additional jars in the classpath).  In addition, if you are on a remote machine and the target machine is not in DNS, you'll have to add it to your hosts file."

- Then make sure you have JAVA_HOME set on he machine and pointing to your JDK 1.7.
- run the appropriate JBOSS jconsole script: JBOSS_HOME/bin/jconsole.sh (linux) or JBOSS_HOME/bin/jconsole.bat (windows) script. You will then be prompted with the normal connect dialog and can enter the appropriate info.

If you do not want to go this route then I could do some research to figure out the appropriate jars that would need to be include for the JDK jconsole.

Comment: yes I have jboss installed in remote machine and we are running the jboss in domain mode. Somehow it is not possible for us to have local jboss installation. Could you please provide the appropriate jars that needs to be added for the JDK console?

Comment: Well there is not a concise list I could find.  You can look at the jconsole.sh script that is under the bin directory of the EAP install.  It adds the jboss-cli-client.jar to to the classpath but it also adds all of the jboss modules to the module path (jconsole -J-Dmodule.path=).  It aactually doesn't look like all of them are required.  It looks like just the modules under JBOSS_HOME/modules/system/layers/base.  So you could try copying the jboss-cli-client.jar and modules over and then configure classpath and module path appropriately for jconsole.

Comment: One other thing (I'm sure you are already aware of) that might be impacting you as well:  By default JBoss AS is bound to 127.0.0.1. To change the address to bind to, you can use the -b switch when starting JBoss AS.  You would use -b0.0.0.0 on startup to allow connectivity from all remote IPs.